# Unable to get StringStream created from marshal to output the data

Tags: nim-lang

Say I have a type like this:

```
type
  Foo = object of RootObj
    f1: string
  Bar = object of Foo
    b1: string
```

And I marshal an instance like this:

```
var bar: Bar
bar.f1 = "FOO"
bar.b1 = "BAR"

var s = newStringStream()
s.store(bar)
```

I can read its data directly:

```
echo s.data # outputs {"b1": "BAR", "f1": "FOO"}
```

But I'm unable to read it using `readLine()` or any other of the reading procs:

```
var line: TaintedString = ""
while s.readLine(line):
    echo line
```

There's simply no output.

---

It works fine if I'm not creating the data using `marshal.store`.

```
var s = newStringStream("foo\nbar")

var line: TaintedString = ""
while s.readLine(line):
    echo line # outputs `foo` then `bar`
```

---

So it seems I'm missing something probably very fundamental and obvious. Any idea what that may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams work like files; when you write to them, the current position within the file moves with the writes. You can observe this with `echo s.getPosition` before and after the call.

If you create a new string stream from a string, the position will be set to zero.

In order to make this work, simply use

```
s.setPosition(0)
```

after a write.

Comment: Like I said, something fundamental and obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

StringStream has the same position value for both reading and writing. Do you do setPosition to 0 before trying to read?